# How to particular column as row

Tags: sql, pivot

My current Data is sql

```
 Date      ClientCode   Amount  
01.02.2020  Z001         20 
01.02.2020  Z004         75 
01.02.2020  Z005         76 
02.02.2020  Z001         40 
03.02.2020  Z001         60 
04.02.2020  Z004         75 
05.02.2020  Z006         75 
06.02.2020  NULL        NULL    
07.02.2020  NULL        NULL    
08.02.2020  NULL        NULL
```

AND I want in this format

```
ClientCode   01-02-2020   02-02-2020   03-02-2020    04-02-2020  05-02-2020  06-02-2020  07-02-2020 
Z001           20.00       40.00           60.00          0.00     0.00         0.00         0.00
Z004           75.00       75.00           0.00           0.00     0.00         0.00         0.00
```

Comment: Have you written any SQL so far? For what db?

Comment: I dont know how to do this

Comment: Date will change based on selector from front end

Comment: My original table contain

Comment: Date    ClientCode Interest Amount
2020-02-01 Z001 18.00 20.00
2020-02-02 Z001 5.00         40.00
2020-02-03 Z001 6.00         60.00
2020-02-01 Z004 18.00 75.00
2020-02-04 Z004 5.00        75.00
2020-02-01 Z005 18.00 76.00
2020-02-05 Z006 17.00 75.00

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)